# Get build timestamp on JBoss application

Tags: java, properties, jboss

We have a web application on JBoss 7.2.
Now I want to display the build timestamp in my UI for debugging purposes, so I added

- a properties file looking like that:

```
version=${pom.version} 
build.date=${timestamp}
```

- in the POM properties:

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

On build, this successfully generates a .properties file with the correct values, e.g.

```
version=0.1-SNAPSHOT
build.date=2021-08-25 12:00
```

However, when deployed, that properties file isn't available anymore. I get a FileNotFoundException when my frontend bean tries to access the file via

```
String propertyPath = "src/main/resources/version.properties";
try (InputStream properties = new FileInputStream(propertyPath)) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(properties);
}
...
```

Now of course I can add the properties to my standalone.xml, but I wasn't able to replace the values during build time. Any tips on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing makes total sense. You are attempting to read the file using the source code path `src/main/resources/version.properties`. Since you have built your app and created a jar out of it, the file in question no longer resides under this path.

You should therefore attempt to load the file using the `classloader`. Check more on that [here](https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

Comment: Worked flawlessly, for some reason all I've found before mentioned putting the properties in the standalone.xml instead. Thanks!

Comment: Happy that it worked. You can also accept the answer since it helped you out.